# Not able to read file in jenkins using java code

Tags: java, jenkins

I am able to read a file using java,File is in eclipse workspace.
My file location is:src\test\resources
So,I have given like this.
String filePath = "\src\test\resources\ARImport_Copy3.csv";

This is working fine but when i am running in jenkins ,I am getting not able to load file messages.

Please provide me the solution.

Comment: This isn't a place for someone to just provide you the solution. Please post what you have tried and we will try to help you fix the problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Reading file directly from filesystem is not flexible. You can't control what working directory would be when executed by different tools in different environments.

It is more reliable to read a resource file from classpath like this:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/ARImport_Copy3.csv");
File testFile = new File(url.getFile());
```

A broader discussion you will find here: [Easy way to get a test file into JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597271/easy-way-to-get-a-test-file-into-junit)