# How to use Junit Testcase with Git OAUTH callback servlet

Tags: java, servlets, github, junit, oauth

Can anyone give me brief idea about this? I have just used url connection to get the code and again url connection to get the access code.

I am using Java Servlet and not spring framework.

Comment: JUnit doesn't provide any specific tool to test connection calls etc. It just provides a general framework for unit test

Comment: Anyway, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2597812/1339429) answer + Mockito may help you to understand how to organize a test for this use case