# How to populate yml property file in JUnit 5 test without build spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, properties-file

Let's say that I have a service that took a property file from the `application.yml` file:

```
orders:
  batch-size: 2
```

and read by @Value annotation:

```
@Value("${orders.batch-size}")
private String ordersBatchSize;
```

to conduct data partitioning.

I am writing the JUnit tests and would like to get the above property from the `application.yml` file which is in the resources. Problem is that the JUnit test property is always null. My JUnit class test is annotated with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.
I don't want to build Spring context by annotating the class with `@SpringBootTest`.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996383/10596295), I need to populate the property file but I tried probably everything without a desirable result.

Attempts so far:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classUnderTest, "field", "value")
```

or

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
InputStream inputStream =this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.yml");
yaml.load(inputStream);
```

or

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileReader("/application.properties"));
```

or

```
System.setProperty("orders.batch-size", "2");
```

or:

```
public static Properties fetchProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:application.yml");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            properties.load(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // exception logic
        }
    return properties;
}
```

or hints from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53117490/10596295) topic but it didn't bring a desirable solution.

I will be grateful for suggestions on how to fix this issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the type should be an integer.

```
@Value("${orders.batch-size}")
private Integer ordersBatchSize;
```

Then using the reflections utils is quite a common approach. Note the field name has to match.

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classUnderTest, "ordersBatchSize", 100)
```

A better way is using a setter (if available) in the method annotated with `@BeforeEach`.

```
@BeforeEach
public void beforeEach() {
    classUnderTest.setOrdersBatchSize(100);
}
```

Finally, the best way is to define `application.yml` in the `test/resources` folder which Spring Boot takes with priority for sake of testing:

```
orders.batch-size=100
```

Comment: Gosh, I didn't think about the trivial setter method for this @Value parameter. It's working fine.

Comment: The property file is read by test, don't know why but the first and the second approach works fine. Cheers!